# Travel health insurance in Europe that does not require European Health Insurance Card

Tags: europe, health, insurance, eu-citizens

I was looking for a new travel insurance policy recently for travel within Europe and what I was never aware of is that [many insurance policies require you to have an European Health Insurance Card (EHIC) for the cover to be valid](http://www.moneysupermarket.com/travel-insurance/ehic/). I have looked at quite a few policies and this does appear to be the case. Two questions:

- Is is **mandatory** to carry an EHIC to be admitted to a hospital? The wording in policies seems to be confusing as they say excess will be waived in case an EHIC is used. But if I'm willing to pay the excess amount, am I still covered otherwise?
- Are there travel insurance policies that do NOT require an EHIC to be carried for the policy to be valid?

(Yes I know an EHIC is free to apply for but I wanted to get a travel insurance that would work without it, just in case I am not carrying / don't have an EHIC on me.)

Comment: Even if you don't have your EHIC with you, you can apply for a refund for the expenses from your national health insurance organization for services that are covered by the EHIC. Granted, it could take weeks, but you will eventually get your money back. The card is nothing more than a handy proof that you are paying your health insurance back home.

Comment: @mindcorrosive Does that mean if I need to go to the hospital, I will not be turned away if I don't have an EHIC? What I am also concerned about is whether without an EHIC, an insurance company will refuse to cover me for charges beyond what EHIC covers.

Comment: I would expect that a European insurer would sell you health coverage that doesn't depend on an EHIC card, but it would be the same coverage they would sell to someone not eligible for free healthcare anywhere in Europe, and would thus be  enormously expensive - on a par with coverage to the US.

Comment: @DJClayworth Not necessarily. In some situations it was possible to get private insurance that was more expensive than “regular” health insurance but still cheaper than in the US (the particular example I have in mind is not current anymore). In most European countries, health care is not free in the way the NHS is. People don't pay for it out of pocket thanks to mandatory/subsidized insurance and electronic claims but providers are not state employees and there is a price for each service they provide. The things is that this price is regulated and often much lower than in the US.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee Are you a British (or even EU citizen) ? If not an EHIC card doesn't apply to you.

Comment: @Simon Isn't the relevant criterion being covered by a statutory health insurance/system in the EU (which most residents are or at least can be, no matter where they come from, in the EU countries I know) rather than citizenship per se?

Comment: @Annoyed This is a grey area, which I'm not entirely sure of (at least for other europeans/non Brits).I'm not sure how EHIC relates to those people (maybe thats the reason E111 in the UK was changed to EHIC to be more in line with a card that is similar in the EU). In my mind its actually getting more complex. I'm might go on Meta to ask for suitability of a question regarding EHIC (unless its already been asked). I'll do a search at some point.

Comment: I can confirm that residents, not just citizens, are covered under the NHS / EHIC in the UK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**

- Get the card no matter what if you are travelling for extended periods of time in EU. It doesn't cost anything and helps a great deal if an unfortunate situation occurs.
- If you can't present your card for some reason, you might have to pay ordinary rates (could be very costly!), but you can apply for reimbursement from your health authorities back home.
- You will not be refused treatment, if your condition is in any way life-threatening (think acute respiratory or debilitating diseases, broken limbs, etc.).

---

The [European Health Insurance Card](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=509&langId=en) (EHIC) is a handy piece of plastic that allows you to receive the same medical care in another EU state as you would in your home country. You will receive for free the same services that you would otherwise get free in your home country, however rates for paid services would differ, but will definitely be close to what you would pay home (as opposed to rates given to non-insured individuals). You are also eligible for medical care if you have some chronic condition that requires specialized treatment (for example, kidney dialysis). You'll need to check with your local health authorities about what conditions are covered, in which countries, and whether you'll have to pay for the treatment.

EHIC are free (besides probably a small administrative fee for handling the documentation if you apply offline).

Let's cut to the chase here, and allow me to plug in the [European Commission](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=509&langId=en). From their [FAQ](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=857&langId=en&intPageId=1304):

> **What happens if I travel without the card and need medical treatment?**
>
> If the need arises, you will still receive the treatment necessary to enable you to continue your holiday without having to return home for treatment. But remember that the card will make it easier for you to access free medical care on the spot or for you to be reimbursed if you have to pay up front. That is why, **when you travel to another Member State of the European Economic Area or Switzerland**, whether for private or professional reasons, **you are strongly advised to do so with a European Health Insurance Card**.

On the topic of reimbursement, this is where it gets hairy. You are indeed able to ask for reimbursement from your health insurance agency back home if you present them with the relevant medical and billing documentation. However, this procedure could be quite lengthy (months, I believe), and there's no guarantee that you'll get back everything. Note that it's best that you apply when you are still abroad -- ask the administration in the hospital about details, and consult your local health authorities.

> **Can a doctor refuse to treat me if I have forgotten my card?**
>
> Medical ethics dictate that **a doctor cannot refuse to treat you** if your state of health requires treatment. However, there is no guarantee that your costs will be reimbursed under the same conditions as if you had been able to prove that you had social security insurance at the time by presenting the card or an equivalent document. **The doctor or medical establishment might well ask you to pay the full cost or to pay up front a proportion of the costs which an insured person in that same Member State would not be asked to pay**. In an emergency your local health authority might be able to help by faxing or e-mailing you a provisional replacement certificate, which gives you the same protection as the European Health Insurance Card.

and finally,

> **What should I do if, during or before my visit, I suddenly realise that I have forgotten or lost my card?**
>
> If you have forgotten or lost your card, you can ask your local authority to fax or e-mail you a provisional replacement certificate. This will give you the same entitlement as the card does.

(emphasis mine everywhere)

I've lived abroad in another EU country than my own, and I can tell you from experience that in the (fortunately very few) cases I had to use it, it significantly sped up the procedure of receiving medical care. For non life-threatening conditions, you would otherwise wait for some time until they collect and process all necessary information from you. If you have a card, all personal information they need (that is, your names, national ID number, permanent address, etc.) are already in the system.